# Patch for EOS Servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, patch-management

My company have got a few Windows 2008 servers that have already reached end of support. We are delaying the decommissioning of the server and I am thinking of controls that can help to mitigate risks.

Doing a rough check, i noticed that there are security patches from 2018 not installed, are we able to patch them at this point of time since it was already reached end of support?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're able to patch them. I would suggest installing all available updates.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase and install [Extended Security Updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/extended-security-updates). This grants you at most 22 more months, as the program is already in year 2 of 3.

ESU also is required for support from Microsoft. Not having this would be a risk to mitigate.